# CSS: force spacing between li with icon elements, disregarding text

Tags: css, css-float

I have this kind of a quite trivial top menu:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <i icon-something></i>
    <a href ="/link">text</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <i icon-another></i>
    <a href ="/link">longer text</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

As usual it's floated left and the icon is above the text.

with the following (less) styling:

```
.mainMenu
{
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  top: 10px;

  a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:11px;
    position: relative;
    top:-15px;
    line-height: 12px;
    display:inline-block;

  };
  li {
    width: 24px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right:45px; //<=my problem
  }
  [class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"] {
    font-size:24px;

  }

}
```

my problem:
I need the spacing between **icons** to be set to 45px. but I the way I currently do it the spacing is set between the whole `li` elem.  since some text is longer then the other. this causes the next text to the right to move to the right. and the spacing to grow, which is unwanted. I'm sure there is a way around this, I'll be glad for some help about this.

Comment: Tip: If you're using margin-right, the last link will have an unecessary margin on the right. You would be better of to use margin-left: 45px. And set margin-left to 0 on the first li. li:first-child{ margin-left: 0; }

Comment: I'm not sure If I understand your problem. But I think changing width: 24px to max-width: 24px will solve your problem.

Comment: I've created a CodePen with your example: http://codepen.io/neagle/pen/viufh I believe it's already working the way you want. If the page you're working on isn't, it's because of styles you haven't included here.

Comment: Have you tried floating your icons left? Or even better using display:inline-block;